# How to use noParse in webpack?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I want to exclude this from my webpack file, by using this line of code given to me below.

`noParse: /node_modules\/localforage\/dist\/localforage.js/,`

But no matter what I try I it keeps on saying errors like

> ReferenceError: Unknown plugin "add-module-exports" specified in C:/..../node_modules\localforage\.babelrc

Here is my webpack config file:

```
var path = require('path');
 var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

 module.exports = {
   entry: './app/index.js',
   output: {
     path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
     filename: 'index_bundle.js',
     publicPath: '/'
   },
   devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
  },
   module: {
     rules: [
       { test: /\.(js)$/, use: 'babel-loader' },

       { test: /\.css$/, use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ]}
     ]
   },
   plugins: [
     new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
       template: 'app/index.html'
     })
  ]
};
```

Comment: it's not very clear. Where is `noParse: /node_modules\/localforage\/dist\/localforage.js/,` written?

Comment: well I am not familiar with webpack, I want to exclude node_modules and localforage.js but I dont know where to do it.

Comment: You shouldn't exclude `node_modules`. why do you want to exclude  `node_modules` folder?

Comment: I dont know why also, but thats what this module is telling me to do for it to work with webpack `https://github.com/localForage/localForage` it says `Webpack will emit a warning about using a prebuilt javascript file which is fine. If you want to remove the warning you should exclude localforage from being parsed by webpack using the following conf :

module: {
  noParse: /node_modules\/localforage\/dist\/localforage.js/,
  loaders: [...],`

I want to be able to use the LocalForage

Answer (score 0):

You can use `localForage 1.3+` version with webpack. You should add `noParse` in your config.

```
var path = require('path');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
module.exports = {
    entry: './app/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'index_bundle.js',
        publicPath: '/'
    },
    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true,
    },
    module: {
        noParse: /node_modules\/localforage\/dist\/localforage.js/,
        rules: [{
            test: /\.(js)$/,
            exclude: /localforage/,
            use: 'babel-loader'
        }, {
            test: /\.css$ / ,
            use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
        }]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: 'app/index.html'
        })
    ]
};
```

Comment: i got an error `[1] ERROR in ./node_modules/localforage/dist/localforage.js
[1] Module build failed: ReferenceError: Unknown plugin "add-module-exports" specified in "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Documents\\ProgramWebsites\\webpackreact\\node_modules\\localforage\\.babelrc" at 0` still the same error :/

Comment: @Mr.Banks what version of localforage do you use?

Comment: I used version 1.5.0

Comment: @Mr.Banks I have updated my answer and `added` exclude to babel.